# Passing interface type (not implementing class type) as argument in java

Tags: java, oop, class, methods, arguments

I am developing a "Service Provider" (quite similar to Google juice).
Its job is to map arbitrary class_1 or interface to *class_2* that *can be instantiated* and either implements class_1 (if class_1 was an *interface*) or is/extends class_1 (if class_1 was not an interface).

So currently I have method

```
public <T> void map(Class<T> key, Class<? extends T> service)
```

the problem with the code is that I can map interface type to interface type like

```
ServiceProvider sp = new ServiceProvider();
sp.map(IParent.class, IChild.class);
```

this perfectly compiles giving no error (IChild extends IParent).
Later, of course, when I want to:

```
IParent obj = sp.getService(IParent.class); //look for IParent mapping and instantiate the proper object
```

I am receiving  java.lang.InstantiationException.

**So the question is:**

How to declare map() method, in such a way that compiler checks that the 2nd argument is class *implementing or extending* the 1st argument and is not an interface?
(**The point is to get compile time error**. I already know how to check this in run time)

Thanks.
PS: yes -- googled a lot, found next to nothing.

**UPD.:**
Thanks all for your time.
Maybe few more words on what is this all about:
The goal is to develop mechanism (ServiceProvider class) which will help me to avoid tight coupling, hard dependencies in my application.
So I have developed/adopted the following philosophy:
"If you want to deliver a 'unit' (piece of *reusable* software) -- declare all public interfaces;
The implementation is your private business, we do not care at all;
If someone wants to use your unit they should request it from the ServiceProvider by 
1. At the startup they use sp.map(IYuorInterface.class, TheClassImplementingIt.class); 
2. IYuorInterface obj = sp.getService(IYuorInterface.class);
You are responsible to make TheClassImplementingIt class 'instantiatable' (constructors, security, class is not abstract etc); if not -- it is quite OK to get run-time exceptions.

What is the benefit?

It is quite obvious -- at any given time any other developer can reimplement IYuorInterface map it with ServiceProvider and then all the application will use it without having to change a single line of code.
(the simplest case when it would be needed -- Unit testing)

So my point/question is: the second argument in the map() method must be of type Class which represents a Class, not Interface and it should be 'assign compatible' with the 1st argument.

In other words when I do map(ISomeIterface.class, Something.class); the **object** (instance) of Something should be usable like this:

```
ISomeIterface obj = sp.getService(ISomeIterface.class);
//or in other words, just for example -- the Something can be used like this:
ISomeIterface obj = new Something();
```

This is why Factories, as suggested by some answers are not acceptable, the ServiceProvider class is already kind of "factory"

---

..and it seems like Java's Class object represents both classes and interfaces and there is no way to distinguish at compile time is really class or interface..

But anyways -- thanks to all.

Comment: You already declared map() so that the 2nd argument is class implementing or extending the 1st argument. InstantiationException shows that there is a problem creating an instance (say, no nullary constructor). You should provide the sources of getService(), IParent, and the stack trace.

Comment: I think you're out of luck on this one: sometimes, the compiler cannot possibly know the exact value of the second argument, e.g. `sp.map(IParent.class, someMethodThatReturnsClassDerivedFromIParent());` will compile, but the return value will not be known until the runtime. I think that checking the second parameter at run-time is your best bet.

Comment: I don't understand. If the implementation is your business, why does the client have to provide an implementation class?

Answer (score 0):

You can find out whether a Class is a concrete, instantiable class using

```
public boolean isConcrete(Class<?> input)
{
    if (input.isInterface())
         return false;

    if (Modifier.isAbstract(input.getModifiers()))
         return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: That's runtime; OP wants compile-time " (The point is to get compile time error. I already know how to check this in run time)"

Comment: @TheCat that is runtime check and I am 99% sure he known that already.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to check at compile time if the `Class` object represents an instanciable class.

Even in the case of a class, it could be abstract or it could lack a no-arg constructor.

As an alternative, I'd suggest that you use a Factory object instead of the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

What if instead of the second argument, you could pass a factory instead.

```
interface IInterface{
    void go();
}

class IInterfaceImpl implements IInterface{
    public void go(){}
}

interface Factory<T>{
    T createInstance();
}

class FactoryImpl implements Factory<IInterface>{

    @Override
    public IInterface createInstance() {
        //you need to return an instance of IInterface, which can only be a class
        return new IInterfaceImpl();
    }
}
```